# InvalidCastException on LINQ-2-SQL Model When Inserting

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, .net

I am getting an InvalidCastException when trying to insert an item into a database using LINQ-to-SQL. As far as I can tell, everything is the proper type.

The SQL table is (abridged):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Timer](
    [TimerId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SessionId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Action] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ActionId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Timer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TimerId] ASC
)
```

The LINQ model is (abridged):

```
public partial class Timer
{

    [Column(AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
    public int TimerId { get; set; }

    [Column(DbType = "NVarChar(64) NOT NULL", CanBeNull = false)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Column(DbType = "DateTime NOT NULL")]
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

    [Column(DbType = "UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL")]
    public Guid SessionId { get; set; }

    [Column(DbType = "NVarChar(50) NOT NULL", CanBeNull = false)]
    public string Action { get; set; }

    [Column(DbType = "UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL")]
    public Guid ActionId { get; set; }

    [Column(DbType = "NVarChar(256) NOT NULL", CanBeNull = false)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

And the offending code is (abridged):

```
using (var ctx = new MyDataContext())
{
    var timer = new Timer();
    timer.Action = "Start";
    timer.ActionId = Guid.NewGuid();
    timer.Description = "foo";
    timer.SessionId = Guid.NewGuid();
    timer.TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
    timer.UserName = "foo";

    ctx.Timers.InsertOnSubmit(timer);
    ctx.SubmitChanges();  // exception thrown here
}
```

The error message says `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.` but it doesnt mention which property is causing the problem. Can anyone spot which property is causing me problems?

Comment: try running SQL profiler and see what is getting executed against the server, try running what you capture and see which value is the problem

Comment: @Ivanov Good idea. I assumed that the cast was happening before the SQL statement was running but it didnt occur that it could be happening on the other side. After profiling, I can confirm that the SQL statement never runs. The exception is thrown before any query is run.

Comment: Can you step through in the debugger and look at the inner exception? It might give you more detail on where the invalid cast is happening.

Comment: Try removing the property assigments one by one to find the problem.

Comment: @Austin there is no inner exception

Comment: @Magnus removing any/all assignments do not affect anything except for UserName which is a foreign key and throws a SqlException because the value cannot be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dropped the table, recreated it, refreshed my model and everything started working without having to change anything else. I dont think anything changed, but clearly .NET likes me again.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to either:

1) Change TimeStamp data type to [DateTime2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) - SQL Server 2008 only.

or

2) Change `timer.TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow;` to `timer.TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();`

Comment: unfortunately, neither of these suggestions worked. the same exception was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem by setting the `Server Data Type` property to `uniqueidentifier` in my DBML.